# python button and key binding positional argument

Tags: python, tkinter

I am new to using tkinter and I have noticed that with the way I am doing it, I can't use both a button and a key binding to rum a function.

```
def call(self) 
   .....


submit = Button(app, text="Call" command = call).grid(row=3, column=0)
call.bind('<Return>', call)
```

this is basically the general idea of what I have got setup, I want both of them to run the function but I keep getting a positional argument for the button if I use 'self' and a positional argument for the enter key if I don't use 'self'

any ideas?

Comment: I don't know if this is relevant to your problem, but you shouldn't assign a Tkinter widget to a variable and `grid` it on the same line. In the code above, `submit` will be `None` because the `grid` method doesn't return anything. You have to do `submit = Button(...)` and then `submit.grid(...)`.

Comment: Alright. I will start doing it that way. Thanks for the advice

Comment: `call.bind(...)` is illegal syntax -- you can't bind to a function, you bind to a widget.

Comment: I didnt know that, it works right now.

Answer (score 1):

I seemed to have fixed it. For my code I had to add `*event` to the function. After that it allowed me to use both the enter key and the given button without any errors.